# Zend_Config_XML encoding issue

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, utf-8

I am creating a XML navigation for my website. This line below is causing a simpleXML issue:

`<label>Osnabr&Atilde;&frac14;ck</label>`

My PHP code, using HTMLentities has changed `Osnabrück` into `OsnabrÃ¼ck`. However, when trying to parse my XML with this line in it, I get this error:

`/application/configs/navigation.xml:318: parser error : Entity 'Atilde' not defined simplexml_load_file()`

Should I not be using htmlentities()? Or is there some kind of setting I'm missing?

Kind Regards

Steve

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using HTML Entities in XML. Using normal UTF-8 characters should be fine.

The occurrence of `OsnabrÃ¼ck` means that at some point, most likely, the city name is processed as ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. It is not `htmlentities()`'s fault. You need to find that point and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iconv() function to convert to utf-8 dynamicaly.

```
iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $text);
```